# Forçar POSTBACK

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou passando informações da variável `click_teste` para um `TextBox` com `id` ***outros*** esse `TextBox` é parâmetro para uma consulta de um `Gridview`.

Preciso que ao receber o dado o textbox faça um `PostBack`, hoje eu tenho que dar um <kbd>Enter</kbd> ou ***clicar em outro controle***.

`Textbox`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="outros" runat="server" 
             AutoPostBack="true" clientIdMode="static" 
             OnTextChanged="outros_TextChanged">
dados
</asp:TextBox>
```

Metodo passar dados:

```
document.getElementById('outros').value = click_teste;
```

---

```
(function (marker, data) {
                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {

                          var click_teste = data.title;
                          document.getElementById('outros').value = click_teste;



                          //alert(click_teste);

                          infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                          alert(click_teste);
                      });
                  })


     <asp:GridView ID="GridView5" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id_programacao_correcao" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id_programacao_correcao" HeaderText="id_programacao_correcao" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id_programacao_correcao"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id_projeto" HeaderText="id_projeto" SortExpression="id_projeto"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="turma" HeaderText="turma" SortExpression="turma"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="deligamento" HeaderText="deligamento" SortExpression="deligamento"></asp:CheckBoxField>
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="linha_viva" HeaderText="linha_viva" SortExpression="linha_viva"></asp:CheckBoxField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="supervisor" HeaderText="supervisor" SortExpression="supervisor"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="eps" HeaderText="eps" SortExpression="eps"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="si" HeaderText="si" SortExpression="si"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="data_execucao" HeaderText="data_execucao" SortExpression="data_execucao"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ref" HeaderText="ref" SortExpression="ref"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="conclusao_correcao" HeaderText="conclusao_correcao" SortExpression="conclusao_correcao"></asp:CheckBoxField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>


        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource8" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:COEX_RPBConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [id_programacao_correcao], [id_projeto], [turma], [deligamento], [linha_viva], [supervisor], [eps], [si], [data_execucao], [ref], [conclusao_correcao] FROM [tbl_programacoes_correcao] WHERE ([ref] = @ref)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="outros" PropertyName="Text" Name="ref" Type="String" DefaultValue="A200675"></asp:ControlParameter>
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:TextBox ID="outros" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" clientIdMode="static" OnTextChanged="outros_TextChanged"> dados</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Qual é o momento que recebe o valor, tem como exemplificar?

Comment: Eu estou usando a API do Google Maps, quando clico em um marcador eu armazeno o nome do marcador na variável click_teste passo esse valor para o campo outros e realizo a consulta no banco usando uma gridview.
O problema é que tenho que realizar o postback no campo outros caso contrario não aparece a gridview.

Comment: (function (marker, data) {
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function e) {
                          
    var click_teste = data.title;
    document.getElementById('outros').value = click_teste;
    //alert(click_teste);
    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    alert(click_teste);
    });
    })

Comment: Você poderia colocar todo o código?

Comment: Todo código não da pq é muito grande, mas segue as partes que sitei.

Comment: Você pode [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar novas informações.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função "__doPostBack", exemplo:

```
function suafuncao() {
    document.getElementById("<%=outros.ClientID%>").value = click_teste;
    __doPostBack("<%=outros.ClientID%>", "");
}
```

Comment: Olá marcelogribeiro, o seu código me ajudou parcialmente, resolveu o  problema do postback mas a gridview esta dento de um modal e ele acaba fechando sozinho.

como ficaria pra dar o postback e manter o modal aberto?

function openModal() {
        $('[id*=modal_ICO]').modal('show');
    }

Comment: Tenta colocar seu textbox dentro de um updatepanel: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="outros" runat="server" 
             AutoPostBack="true" clientIdMode="static" 
             OnTextChanged="outros_TextChanged">dados
</asp:TextBox>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>